# writing child of a blazor component HTML element directly in a Blazor Page

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In my `Blazor WebAssembly` project I have the simple following `blazor component`:

```
<video class="video-class">
    <source src="source_1" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="source_2" type="video/mpeg" />
    Your browser isn't supported!
</video>
```

And to use this component in a page I would simply write the following in the `index.razor` page:

```
@page "/"

<RazorComponentExample>
</RazorComponentExample>
```

However what I would like is to write the following in the `blazor component`:

```
<video class="video-class">
    
</video>
```

And in the `index.razor` page I'd like to use the component like this:

```
@page "/"

<BlazorComponentExample>
    <source src="source_1" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="source_2" type="video/mpeg" />
    Your browser isn't supported!
</BlazorComponentExample>
```

Any idea how please?

Comment: What have you tried?#

Comment: @MisterMagoo nothing because I have no idea what to start with

Comment: This is the very basics of developing components in Blazor. Having "no idea where to start" indicates you should do some learning modules. You will find [Blazor University](https://blazor-university.com) a good starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [`RenderFragment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/components#templated-components), your component should look something like this:

```
<video class="video-class">
    @ChildContent
</video>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your component needs to look like this:

```
<video class="video-class">
  @ChildContent
</video>
@code {
[Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

And then your index page will work.

Razor's default convention for content between the opening and closing tags is to "code" it into a `RenderFragment` called `ChildContent` if such a property exists.  You can then place it where you like in the component by declaring it as `@ChildContent`.